# Not understood output in Telegram Bot from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telegram-bot

I have an action in Telegram controller

```
class TelegramWebhooksController < Telegram::Bot::UpdatesController         
  def start!(*)
    respond_with :message, text: t("I have display number 2")
  end     
end
```

To start poller I run in console

```
Telegram::Bot::UpdatesPoller.new(Telegram.bots[:default], TelegramWebhooksController).start
```

If I text `/start` in bot I get the error

> translation missing: en.I have display number 2

I don't understand why I get the error. Please, help

Comment: as error tells that translation is missing. So remove 't' from text hash. Try: `respond_with :message, text: "I have display number 2"`

Comment: OMG, i stupid, it was logical... Ty very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as error tells that translation is missing. So remove 't' from text hash. 
Try:

```
respond_with :message, text: "I have display number 2"
```